# How to make the ASP.NET_SessionId cookies id as a secure

Tags: cookies

We are using Sitecore 8.2 and We are doing the pen test and reports showing `ASP.NET_SessionId` is not enabled as a secure.

I had tried the below things in `web.config` file but this is not working properly.

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

And in `<forms>` set `requireSSL` too.

```
<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="true" />
```

Is there any other possible way to change the SSL true for the cookies?

Comment: Are you sure you applied them in the right place in `web.config`? Setting like that works for me: `<system.web>    <httpCookies requireSSL="true" />    <authentication>      <forms requireSSL="true" ...    </authentication>`

Comment: No for me it is not working. It is not applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with the approaches you have tried, as you mentioned in the question, I would suggest you add `HTTPOnly` flag as appropriate for your cookies too. Add this to your `web.config` file.

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

References:

https://andrewwburns.com/2016/10/21/secure-your-sitecore-cookies/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/179172/implement-domain-http-only-and-secure-cookie-attri

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks Sumit, After adding the httpOnlyCookies="true" it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<system.web>` element, add the following element:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

However, if you have a `<forms>` element in your `system.web\authentication` block, then this will override the setting in `httpCookies`, setting it back to the default `false`.

In that case, you need to add the `requireSSL="true"` attribute to the forms element as well.

So you will end up with:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms requireSSL="true">
            <!-- forms content -->
        </forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

References

- [httpCookies Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms228262(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.requiressl?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Web_Security_FormsAuthentication_RequireSSL)

Hope it helps!